# Can't read storage item from migration script, however can read from polkadot.js.app

Tags: migration

Here are the details, I need to do a storage migration for a pallet. I can read the storage item from the [polkadot.js.app](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frhala-api.phala.network%2Fws#/chainstate), as shown below:
[image: register info of KSM]

however, I can not read it from migration script(**returned None**), code is:

```sh
let reg_info = RegistryInfoByIds::<T>::get(asset_id).ok_or(Error::<T>::AssetNotRegistered)?;
```

I assume the storage item must exist if we can query from the polkadot.js.app. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: What is the value of `asset_id` in your script?

Comment: @forgetso It's a type of pallet_assets::AssetId, for example:

`let roc_id: <T as pallet_assets::Config>::AssetId = 0u32.into();`

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are defining your storage?

Comment: @PawanBisht Here is the [storage definition](https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/62737d6d31cc49b6f1aac7ffd58a116173143c4a/pallets/assets-registry/src/lib.rs#L194), and here is the [migration script](https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/62737d6d31cc49b6f1aac7ffd58a116173143c4a/pallets/assets-registry/src/migration.rs#L33).

Comment: Are you importing your pallet for accessing the storage?

Comment: Or what error you are getting?

Comment: @PawanBisht Yes, I have imported it. And the errors:
`Error: Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed`

And i also got message: 
`Corrupted state at [247, 134, 14, 82, 179, 211, 102, 13, 227, 92, 128, 132, 85, 236, 72, 54, 194, 126, 131, 60, 159, 34, 33, 143, 86, 41, 12, 5, 63, 19, 39, 211, 180, 222, 242, 92, 253, 166, 239, 58, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, I think that storage i query maybe corrupted, but why i can acces via polkadot.js.app? BTW, i read another storage item in migration script, it works well.

Comment: Because I have added a field on RegisterInfo at the end, I guess I need to translate it to the new value. If I want to query it with the new RegisterInfo on an old runtime, it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating types in a runtime migration, you must read the "old" storage using the old storage type.

Imagine you have an item originally stored as:

```rust
struct Item {
    id: u32,
    field1: Field,
}
```

Then imagine you update the item to be:

```rust
struct Item {
    id: u32,
    field1: Field,
    field2: Field,
}
```

If you were to try to read this storage item after updating the `struct Item`, you will get the "corrupt state" error because on your blockchain, there is no `field2`, and thus, when trying to read from state to create the new `Item`, it will fail.

Instead, a common pattern for migrations is to write a special type which acts as a way to read the old storage, and then re-write the storage with the new updated struct.

That pattern looks like this:

```rust
mod old {
    pub struct OldItem {
        id: u32,
        field1: Field,
    }

    #[frame_support::storage_alias]
    pub type ItemMap<T> = StorageMap<
        crate::Pallet<T>,
        Twox64Concat,
        u32,
        OldItem<T>,
    >;
}

fn migration() {
    // Note here we are reading from `old`, which has our old type.
    for (_key, old_item) in old::ListNodes::<T, I>::iter() {
        // Note here we are using the `crate::Item`, which has the updated object.
        let new_item = crate::Item {
             id: old_item.id,
             field1: old_item.field1,
             // Here we just duplicate field1, but you may have your own logic...
             field2: old_item.field1,
        };

        // Note that we write back to `crate::ItemMap` which uses the new type.
        crate::ItemMap::<T>::insert(old_item.id, new_item);
    }
}
```

There are plenty of examples in Substrate, but here is one:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/bags-list/src/migrations.rs

Comment: Thanks, I finally used the [translate()](https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/33d3c391bc04b803b2d3de6775567d7da18f0ff9/pallets/assets-registry/src/migration.rs#L48) method to convert an old item to a new one. Sure an old item also needs to be declared to help read from the storage.

Comment: If you found your own answer to the question, please do post the answer and mark the question as resolved :)

Comment: Apologize for the late reply. I solved the problem by using the `translate()` method provided by the substrate storage map. And definitely no matter what approach we still need to define an old type to make sure the storage decoding before migration is done can succeed. Here is the [details](https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/33d3c391bc04b803b2d3de6775567d7da18f0ff9/pallets/assets-registry/src/migration.rs).